# Get dynamic query string paramters from URL - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string

I've an URL where the query string parameters are dynamic. I need to read them in my JavaScript. What I've done is

I've used the following code to read all the query string parameters.

**For example:**

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var searchObject = $location.search();
// searchObject  => {foo: 'bar', baz: 'xoxo'}
```

I also have an array with the keys. Here my array will have **foo** and **baz**.

**For example:** `var list = ["foo", "baz"];`

So how do I get the values from the URL with the keys I've in my list array?

I tried this way

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
                {
                    alert(searchObject.list[i]);
                }
```

But this gave me an Error in the console **searchObject.list** is undefined.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you want:

```js
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    alert(searchObject[list[i]]);
}
```

Loop though the items of list, using each one as the key to the searchObject object.

http://jsfiddle.net/8vekqezj/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
    alert(searchObject[list[i]]);
}
```

I'm not sure why you have included the `list` property, `searchObject` is just and (as the name suggests) a plain old javascript object.

Comment: ```searchObject``` is (as you say) a plain old javascript object. So why are you indexing into it with the indexes of the list array?

Comment: You're right, my bad ;) now we have the same solution :D

Answer (score 1):

May be using the AngularJS utility:

```
angular.forEach(list, function(key){
  alert(searchObject[key]);
});
```